# Will Mountain Lion run on an early 2008 MacBook White?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, macos

I know it isn't in Apple's list of supported Macs, but I want to know if anyone has tried it.

Also, my Mac has 4GB of ram and plenty of disk space. It currently runs Lion.

Comment: You want it so bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Steve Moser [says](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57702/11600) there is no support for 32 bit drivers and Mountain Lion will refuse to install on the macs which had 32 bits drivers (someone seems to be too lazy to rewrite them?).

If this answer is not the one you want to hear, then you can install Mountain Lion the hard way. Because there is a way (which worked for [the preview](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/18/install-os-x-mountain-lion-developer-preview-on-old-unsupported-macs/)).

You will need another compatible mac (support) and you will have to do some hard drive switching.

The idea goes as follow:

- Get Mountain Lion
- On the target Mac remove the hard drive (target drive)
- On the support Mac insert the hard drive (USB or internally)
- Install Mountain Lion on the target drive
- Put the target drive back in the target Mac
- Boot on the target drive holding Cmd + V And write down the ID given in the error message "Incompatible Mac detected: ..."
- Put the target drive back to the support Mac and on this drive in `/System/Library/CoreServices` edit `PlatformSupport.plist`

  - Add your board ID in the `SupportedBoardIds` section.
  - Add your model ID in the `SupportedModelProperties` section.
- Put the target drive to the target Mac
- Boot

You should be able to get to the desktop but without hardware graphics support.

To enable the graphics hardware support you will have to install the right kernel extentions. You could use [kexthelper](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26865/kext-helper/).

---

**EDIT**: To avoid all the hard drive switching and messing with internal components you can boot the target Mac in the so conveniently named "target mode" and connect it to the support Mac on which you could install the OS to the target drive and then boot on the target drive to edit the plist files.

Comment: The comment about laziness isn't constructive ;-)

Comment: No it isn't... Just releasing a little steam ;)

Comment: Steam scalds the dogcows of developers. Moof! ;-)

Comment: commercial strategy... Apple should develop 32 bit drivers for Intel GMA X3100...

Comment: Does this work for newer versions of OS X?

Comment: @www139, my understanding is that Yosemite can run on Macs with GMA X3100 and non official kext. I am not so sure about Sierra as there might be more components with missing drivers. but you can try. Also there is a simpler way then switching hard drives. Using target mode.

Comment: @Coyote I was reluctant to perform the operation because the MacBook is my school computer. However, I just bought a replacement machine. When my MacBook is no longer significant, I might try experimenting. There is a bootable flash drive hack (forgot the name) which supposedly can do this. It would be an easier solution but, sadly, it didn't work when I tried it. Your answer may actually be easiest if it is reliable. The software hack I tried isn't reliable. I couldn't get it working after 3+ attempts.

Answer (score 3):

No, Mountain Lion requires 64-bit graphics drivers and mac formatted drivers don't exist for the graphics in the early 2008 White MacBook.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Mountain Lion on a early white MacBook]

Mountain lion will run on a early white MacBook. Below is a screenshot of my Mac for proof, also you can max the RAM out at 6GB

Comment: how are you experiencing 10.8

Comment: How did you do it? I tried MLPostFactor but it continuously failed. I gave up after trying 3+ times. What was your experience with it? Could you perhaps write a guide in your answer. I remember the documentation on the website being confusing.