# could you force install OSX Mavericks onto a Apple MacBook A1181 early 2008 model if running snow leopard or mountain lion osx

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

iv just bought an Apple MacBook A1181 (white) early 2008 model and was wondering if i could install mavericks on it? in any way shape or form?

Comment: did you do any research, have you tried anything ?

Comment: see also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57698/will-mountain-lion-run-on-an-early-2008-macbook-white

Answer (score 1):

To install Mavericks, you need one of these Macs:

```
iMac (Mid-2007 or later)
MacBook (13-inch Aluminum, Late 2008), (13-inch, Early 2009 or later)
MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid-2009 or later),
MacBook Pro (15-inch or 17-inch, Mid/Late 2007 or later)
MacBook Air (Late 2008 or later)
Mac mini (Early 2009 or later)
Mac Pro (Early 2008 or later)
Xserve (Early 2009)
```

Your Mac also needs:

```
OS X Mountain Lion, Lion, or Snow Leopard v10.6.8 already installed
2 GB or more of memory
8 GB or more of available space
```

There are some attempts reported how to Force Install on non compatible models, but the result is more of a waste of time then a working computer.